# Optimize python algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, python-itertools

I have three sorted lists, examplewise

```
a, b, c = [10,9,8], [9,8,7], [13,5,1]
```

I want to get all the combinations `x, y, z` where `x in a, y in b and z in c` and `1/x + 1/y + 1/z < 1` in the fastest time possible. I've been trying some different approaches,

```
for x, y, z in product(a, b, c):
    if predicative(x,y,z):
        yield (x, y, z)
```

Obviously, this takes too long time considering I'm checking everything, and the lists `a, b, c` are already sorted. I have tried sorting `product(a,b,c)` on the `sum`, but that is reaaally slow, as it uses all the products. My initial plan with having `a, b and c` sorted is so I could break out of the loop as soon as one fails. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile)? The pure Python equivalent implementation is effectively your current approach plus two lines (`else: break`).

Comment: I don't think `takewhile will` work to be honest, as it goes linearly through. The way `product` is sorted, I could easily miss combinations. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Martol1ni Since the data is already sorted, [this](http://ideone.com/dCMAF3) is the best you can get I guess.

Comment: The use of continue isn't right though, is it? If the first one is not valid, the second one will definately not be valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution that could speed it up a bit would be to store `1/z` for each `z` in `c` in a list, and for each pair of `x,y` in `a,b` - use binary search for the highest `1/z` (in the auxillary list) such that `1/x + 1/y + 1/z < 1` - this will effectively trim many search from the 3rd lists and get you some speed up.

This will reduce time complexity to `O(log(n)*n^2 + Y)`, where `Y` is the output size (number of triplets produced).

Note however, that since the output size itself is `O(n^3)` (consider 3 lists with all elements > 3.333) - you cannot avoid the worst case slow time, since you might be needing to generate `n^3` triplets.

If you want only the count however, the approach suggested can easily find it in `O(n^2*logn)`.

Comment: That is very interesting. I will end up with `O(n^3)` whatever I do I suppose.